# Angular assign Oberservable on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, http

I've got the following code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.invoiceService.getIncorrectInvoices().subscribe(data => {
      this.incorrectInvoices = data;
      this.dataSource.data = this.incorrectInvoices
      console.log(this.incorrectInvoices);
    });
    console.log(this.incorrectInvoices);
  }
```

The problem is that `console.log(this.incorrectInvoices);` only gives the expected result on the first `console.log` which is executed second.

I understand that this is because it is a async call, but how can I make sure that `this.incorrectInvoices` gets assigned with the data returned by the http call on ngOnInit()?

Comment: You cannot access the async variable `this.incorrectInvoices` synchronously. All statements that directly depend on it **must** be inside the subscription. There is no way to ensure the console log outside the subscription will print the variable `this.incorrectInvoices` after the assignment except to move it inside the subscription.

Comment: this.incorrectInvoices will be updated with the returned object. You just can't see it as the last console.log will actually fire first (when its empty).

Answer (score 0):

`this.incorrectInvoices` *does* get assigned with the correct data.

You just cannot log it before it is resolved.

One way to see it contains the data you need (besides debugging) would be to bind the property in the HTML template.